# What is the difference between Cerberus Custom Rules and Custom Validators?

Tags: python, cerberus

From the [documentation](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/latest/customize.html#custom-rules), it is not clear to me what the difference in use case for the Custom Rule and the Custom Validators are. In the examples given in the documentation, the only difference is an extra `if` statement that checks the value of `is_odd` in the custom rule. When should I prefer the Custom Rule, and when should I prefer the Custom Validator?

---

Custom Rule

```
schema = {'amount': {'isodd': True, 'type': 'integer'}}
from cerberus import Validator

class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_isodd(self, isodd, field, value):
        """ Test the oddity of a value.

        The rule's arguments are validated against this schema:
        {'type': 'boolean'}
        """
        if isodd and not bool(value & 1):
            self._error(field, "Must be an odd number")
```

---

Custom Validator

```
from cerberus import Validator
schema = {'amount': {'validator': 'oddity'}}

class AValidator(Validator):
    def _validator_oddity(self, field, value):
       if value & 1:
           self._error(field, "Must be an odd number")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the [`validator`](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#validator) rule when you want to delegate validation of a certain field's value to a custom function or method (the latter is references as string in a schema), like so:

```
>>> def oddity(field, value, error):
...   if not value & 1:
...     error(field, "Must be an odd number")

>>> schema = {'amount': {'validator': oddity}}
>>> v = Validator(schema)
>>> v.validate({'amount': 10})
False

>>> v.errors
{'amount': 'Must be an odd number'}

>>> v.validate({'amount': 9})
True
```

Note that the signature of these is fixed, they take exactly `field` (the field's name in the document), `value` and `error` (a method to submit errors) as arguments.

[Custom rules](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/customize.html#custom-rules) can only be defined in a `Validator` subclass. In contrast to the `validator` rule where the validating callable is defined as constraint, for custom rules constraints can be defined in a schema that are also passed to the custom rule implementation (in [this answer's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445016/2489914) it's named `other`). Therefore, the behaviour of a rule can be controlled in a schema.

It appears that the documentation for the `validator` rule is misleading if not plain wrong, and I should go and fix it as soon as possible! Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thank you! Then what is the purpose of declaring `_validator_*` methods in `Validator` subclasses? What use case was there in enabling that functionality? For my case, I want to validate that a given input is a valid Quantity from the Pint package that is greater than 0. I could define a new rule `isvalid_quantity` and write a `_validate_isvalid_quantity` method in the subclass, or I could write a `_validator_quantity` method and specify `quantity` as the `validator` in the schema. Is there a difference between these methods?